# How to use egarch on a ts (in OSX)

Tags: r

`stock.ba` is a `ts` object of monthly stock returns and I would like to fit an eGARCH model, but I keep getting this error using a new download of `rgarch` in R 2.10.1:

```
> stock.ba.egarch <- ugarchfit(stock.ba, spec)
Error in UseMethod("ugarchfit") : 
  no applicable method for 'ugarchfit' applied to an object of class "ts"
```

Here's the (relevant) code

```
stock.ba <- window(stock, start=c(1831, 1), end=c(2010, 2))
spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH"))
stock.ba.egarch <- ugarchfit(stock.ba, spec)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a fix from the library-writer! I had to unclass the ts:

```
stock.ba.egarch <- ugarchfit(spec=spec, data=unclass(stock.ba))
```

I was also being a little casual with my argument placement (as a result of a few unsuccessful iterations).